# Why boldmath fails in a tikz node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, boldmath

I think that probably `\boldmath` is deprecated, although I can't find any "official" reference, but anyway:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) node[draw]{\boldmath \(+\)} (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Fails to compile with a strange:

```
! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.6     \path (0,0) node[draw]{\boldmath \(+\)}
                                                (1,1);
?
```

If I double the braces in the node, as

```
\path (0,0) node[draw]{{\boldmath \(+\)}} (1,1);
```

it works ok:

[image: bold plus in a box]

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: `\boldmath` is not deprecated.

Comment: I seem to recall that tikz only allows a certain number of expansions while looking for the `;` and the full definition of `\boldmath` is rather complicated so perhaps it is too much....

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought it was deprecated for this http://joshua.smcvt.edu/latex2e/_005cboldmath-_0026-_005cunboldmath.html but I see this is not official...

Comment: Not only unofficial it is completely wrong.

Comment: That's definitely a PGF bug.  The node text should not be expanded even if it's collected on a path.

Comment: The problem is that `\boldmath` uses `\aftergroup` and this leaks out of the node.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ti*k*Z has the key `font` (as well as `node font` for such things) with which it works.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (1,0) node[draw,font=\boldmath]{ \(+\)};
    \path (2,0) node[draw,node font=\boldmath]{ \(+\)};
    \path (3,0) node[draw]{ \(+\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in `TiKZ`.  Currently, the workaround is to use an extra level of braces inside the text of the node.

(But generally speaking, `TiKZ` should create this extra level of braces itself, to guard against possible `\aftergroup`.)